# can't inherit interface after migrating project from VS2010 to VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to migrate a project from VS2010 to VS2012 and aside from a few small snags, the biggest problem I'm having is that there is a `public class` that will not inherit an interface.

Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.ExceptionManagement;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.Common;

namespace COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.WebService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://class.ified/Services")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]

    public interface IAssessmentService
    {
```

This is the class trying to inherit the interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.ExceptionManagement;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.Common;
using COMPANY.Common.Logging;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

using COMPANY.PROJECT.BDO;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.Common;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.BDO.Security;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.SurveyAdminServiceReference;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.PatientServiceReference;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.Common.Web.Extensions;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.BDO.ServiceResponse;
using COMPANY.PROJECT.BDO.Enrollment;

using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.WebService
{
    public class AssessmentService : IAssessmentService
    {
```

In VS2010, the project compiles without errors and `AssessmentService` and `IAssessmentService` both appear in light blue text, but in VS2012 `AssessmentService` is in light blue and `IAssessmentService` is in plain black text which to me says that it cannot find the interface even though it's in the same namespace. While this is not causing any build errors on these two particular files, it is causing errors on a code module for a unit test:

`Error  9   The type or namespace name 'AssessmentService' does not exist in the namespace 'COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.WebService' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'`

When I looked at the code module where the build error is occurring, it is `using COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.WebService;` just in case anyone is going to ask that question.

If someone would be able to tell me why the interface can be inherited in VS2010 but not in 2012, that would be most excellent. As well, I've already checked properties for any differences between 2010 and 2012 and made sure they were exactly the same.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Does `COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.WebService` build correctly?  If it doesn't, other projects won't pick it up and you'll see the error you're getting.

Comment: If I comment out the lines of code in the unit test where the build errors occur that project will build successfully, however, `IAssessmentService` still remains in black text.

Answer (score 1):

Build the assembly that contains the interface first. Assuming it build ok, make sure there is a reference to that assembly in the project where you are using it.

You can also check the build order of your projects from the project dependencies tab on the solution properties dialog.

Comment: The unit test that spits out the error does contain a reference to `COMPANY.PROJECT.HL7.WebService`. As I mentioned. It's because the `IAssessementService` interface isn't being inherited even though it's in the same namespace at the class that's trying to use it.